# If $g(x)=\int_{0}^{f(x)}(1+t^{2})dt$ is $C^\infty$ prove $f$ is $C^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $f:U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined in the open set $U$. Suppose $g:U  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x)=\int_{0}^{f(x)}(1+t^{2})dt$ is $C^\infty$. Prove $f$ is $C^\infty$.

Using the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule I can compute $g'(x)$. Let $u=f(x)$, then
\begin{align*}
g'(x)&=\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}\int_{0}^{f(x)}(1+t^{2})dt\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} u}\left (  \int_{0}^{u}(1+t^{2})dt \right )\frac{\mathrm{d}u }{\mathrm{d} x}\\
&=\left ( 1+f(x)^{2} \right )f'(x).
\end{align*}

And so on one can show that
$$
g''(x)=f''(x)+2f(x)f'(x)^2+f(x)^2f''(x).
$$
I can keep computing $g'''(x)$, $g^4(x), \cdots$ but I would never finish so im trying to do the following:

Since $g$ is $C^\infty$ and in the first term of $g^{(n)}$ we have $f^{(n)}$ (n-th) derivative then $f$ must be $C^\infty$.

But i dont feel confident with this solution so Im wondering if there's a better approach.

Comment: You are assuming that $f'$ exists. Isn't that what you want to prove?

Comment: Definitely wrong: circular reasoning as pointed by @Matematleta.

Comment: You're right @Matematleta.

Comment: Don't forget, you're working with functions of $m$ variables, not just one variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much easier:
$$g(x) = h(f(x))$$
with $h\in C^{\infty}$ and bijective (why?) and apply to $h$ the [Inverse Function Theorem](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~andras/174A-2.pdf).

Comment: $h(x)=\int_{0}^{x}(1+t^{2})dt$ so that $g(x)=h(f(x))$ and by hypothesys $h(f(x))$ is $C^\infty$. I still dont see why $h$ is bijective.

Comment: Now I see that $h$ is indeed bijective. Thank you.

Comment: $y=x^3$ is injective but the inverse is not $C^{\infty}$ You need to show that $h'$ is never $0$.

Comment: $h'(x)=x^2+1$ so it's never $0$. But im still unable to prove $f$ is $C^\infty$.

Comment: The inverse theorem tell me that $(h^{-1})'(h(f(x)))=(h'(f(x)))^{-1}$.

Comment: @ipreferpi, $h$ is $C^k$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$, so $h^{-1 }$ is...

Comment: Sorry im dumb,  $h(f(x))=g(x)$ if and only if $h^{-1}(g(x))=f(x)$. So that $f$ is $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: @ipreferpi and I'm dumb for not noticing that the integrand is never zero!

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is the best way to go, but I think you can do it from scratch:

$g(x)=\int_{0}^{f(x)}(1+t^{2})dt=f(x)+\frac{1}{3}f(x)^3$ so

$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-\frac{f(x+h)^3-f(x)^3}{3h}=\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$

$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{3h}(f(x+h)^2+f(x+h)f(x)+f(x)^2)=\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}.$

$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}(1-\frac{1}{3}(f(x+h)^2+f(x+h)f(x)+f(x)^2)=\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}.$

Contiuity of $f$ together with differentibility of $g$ now implies that $f'$ exists at $x$, for $f(x)\neq 1$ and the general result follows by induction.

If  $f(x)= 1$ then assume without loss of generality that $f(0)=0.$ Then, $g(x)=4/3$ and

$\frac{f(x+h)-1}{h}-\frac{f(x+h)^3-1}{3h}=\frac{g(x+h)-4/3}{h}\Rightarrow f'(1)=\frac{1}{3}f'(0)\cdot0^2+g'(1)=g'(1)$

Comment: A true tour of force. Upvoted.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla sí le di una vueltezota!